# Need Help setting Rule for field to require Attachment before allowing a selection from a drop down,

Tags: attachments, infopath-rules

I have a form field which has 3 different selections in the drop down, In Progress.. On Hold.. and Completed.

Since the form is opened many times before marked complete, I do not need a code that requires an attachment before submitting. I need a rule which would make having the attachment which we want to require attached before the "Completed" status would be selectable from the drop down and the form submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with a very small workflow that runs when an item is created, and when it is changed:
[image: Workflow Start Options]

In the workflow itself, I checked the conditions you specified. If those conditions are not met, the workflow will adjust the status (I called the column "Choice") to a different status (I chose "On Hold"), and email the modifying user that their status was automatically changed due to not having an attachment:

[image: Workflow Details]
[image: Email Example]

Please let me know if this helps you!

Best,

Chris Dennett